# How do I show a div on fancybox load

Tags: fancybox-3

I have a page that contains CSS that hides a div class

```
.sectiondiv.showhide {
  display: none;
}
```

But when loading the same page within a fancybox iframe I'd like to have that same content to be visible.  I've tried the following CSS in the jquery.fancybox.css but that doesn't help.  Any suggestions for this fix?

Answer (score 0):

Why don`t you simply check if page is inside fancyBox iframe and just add custom CSS if needed? You can create links like 'mypage.html?fancyboxed=true' to make checking easier.

Another solution would be to use aferLoad callback to access iframe contents and do some modifications.

This is how you can access some element within iframe:

```
$.fancybox.getInstance().current.$content.find('iframe').contents().find('body')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this information is too vague for me to do anything with.  Sorry.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: But what part you can not understand? Basically, if this CSS rule exists, then, obviously, you either create some overriding rule (depending on some condition) or use JS to change inline style for these elements. I pointed you to both possible solutions.